# VSCode remote Python virtual environment

Tags: python, linux-mint, remote, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

Here is how the thing doesn't work:

The project source code is located on a remote machine. The Python virtual environment is installed in the project's root directory (using venv).

I sshfs the project folder and start local VSCode. It detects the virtual environment, but doesn't see pylint or other packages installed in it.

Python 3.6.7
  VS Code - latest version
  OSs - Debian 9 remote, Linux Mint 19 local
  Both sshfs connection and venv installation are performed under the same account.

Is there some special way a virtual environment should be set up to be usable remotely?